# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80

Tags: python, utf-8, caffe

I'm trying to download BVLC-trained model and I'm stuck with this error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 110: invalid start byte
```

I think it's because of the following function ([complete code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/scripts/download_model_binary.py))

```
  # Closure-d function for checking SHA1.
  def model_checks_out(filename=model_filename, sha1=frontmatter['sha1']):
      with open(filename, 'r') as f:
          return hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest() == sha1
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The error message is quite clear. Either your file is not UTF8 at all, or it is damaged.

Comment: That is what I got when I try to print `f` 

`<_io.TextIOWrapper name='models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel' mode='r' encoding='utf8'>`

Comment: Interesting. So what happens when you specify the file encoding explicitly?  Something like `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')`  ?

Comment: I have tried to modify the 2nd line with this `with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:` but I got the same err

Comment: No, do *not* tell Python it is UTF8. Unless you are sure it ought to be - but Python is telling you it is *not* valid UTF8, but something else. Open the file with a good code editor and see what's inside.

Comment: I can't it's a .caffemodel file and it's very messy there, I'm using vim. I don't think it's supposed to be a readable file.

Comment: Glad you found both answers helpful! Note that you can only mark one as accepted; the choice is entirely up to you which one you pick. :-)

Comment: Yeah, thanks Martijn, I've up-voted your answer as it is what I'm looking for as well, but I found DSM post it first. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: I stand corrected, Rax.  My apologies.  It wasn't my intention to mislead.

Comment: np, thanks Phil for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are opening a file that is not UTF-8 encoded, while the default encoding for your system is set to UTF-8.

Since you are calculating a SHA1 hash, you should read the data as *binary* instead. The `hashlib` functions require you pass in bytes:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    return hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest() == sha1
```

Note the addition of `b` in the file mode.

See the [`open()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

> *mode* is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to `'r'` which means open for reading in text mode. *[...]* In text mode, if *encoding* is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding. (For reading and writing raw bytes use binary mode and leave *encoding* unspecified.)

and from the [`hashlib` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hash-algorithms):

> You can now feed this object with bytes-like objects (normally bytes) using the update() method.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify to open the file in binary mode, so `f.read()` is trying to read the file as a UTF-8-encoded text file, which doesn't seem to be working.  But since we take the hash of *bytes*, not of *strings*, it doesn't matter what the encoding is, or even whether the file is text at all: just open it, and then read it, as a binary file.

```
>>> with open("test.h5.bz2","r") as f: print(hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-fdba09d5390b>", line 1, in <module>
    with open("test.h5.bz2","r") as f: print(hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest())
  File "/home/dsm/sys/pys/Python-3.5.1-bin/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb8 in position 10: invalid start byte
```

but

```
>>> with open("test.h5.bz2","rb") as f: print(hashlib.sha1(f.read()).hexdigest())
21bd89480061c80f347e34594e71c6943ca11325
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there is not a single hint in the documentation nor src code, I have no clue why, but using the b char (i guess for binary) totally works (tf-version: 1.1.0):

```
image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(filename, 'rb').read()
```

[For more information, check out: gfile](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a0d784bdd31b27e013a7eac58a86ba62e86db299/tensorflow/python/platform/gfile.py#L54)