# Python 'utf-8' codec stop message with IIS log

Tags: python-3.x, csv

With the following python code

```
import csv
log_file = open('190415190514.txt', 'r')
all_data = csv.reader(log_file, delimiter=' ')
data = []
for row in all_data:
    data.append(row)
```

to read a big file containing

```
2019-04-15 00:00:46 192.168.168.29 GET / - 443 - 192.168.168.80 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+PRTG+Network+Monitor+(www.paessler.com);+Windows) - 200 0 0 0
```

I get this error

```
 File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
   for row in datareader:
 File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1284: invalid start byte
```

I think there is no problem with the data file since it is a IIS log file. If there is any encoding issue, how can I locate that line? I am also not sure if my problem is the same [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825972/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you opened the file as `'r'` instead of `'rb`', python is trying to decode it as utf-8.   The contents of the file are apparently not valid utf-8, so you're getting an erorr.   You can find the line number of the offending line like this:

```py
with open('190415190514.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        try:
            line.decode('utf-8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            print (f'{e} at line {i+1}')
```

You probably should be passing `errors` or `encoding` to open.  see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: OK I see some `%2f%69%6e%64%` characters which seems to be non-english words. How can I ignore those line?

Comment: If you just want to ignore thhem you could pass `errors='ignore'` to `open`