# Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, bytecode

I am fetching data from a catalog and it's giving data in bytes format.

Bytes data:

```
b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00%\x83\xa0\x08\x01\x00\xbb@\x00\x00\x05p 
\x02\x00>\xf3\x00\x00\x00}\x02\x00`\x03\xef0\x00\x00\r\xc0 
\x06\xf0>\xf3\x00\x00\x02\x88\x02\x03\xec\x03\xef0\x00\x00/.....'
```

While converting this data in string or any readable format I'am getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Code which I used(Python 3.7.3):

```
blobs = blob.decode('utf-8')
```

AND

```
import json
json.dumps(blob.decode())
```

I've also used `pickle`, `ast` and `pprint` but they are not helpful here.

What I tried:

- [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)
- [error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)
- [Python 3 CSV file giving UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte error when I print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21504319/python-3-csv-file-giving-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-err)
  ['utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825972/utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80)
- [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518023/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-3131-invali)
- https://www.edureka.co/community/52722/unicodedecodeerror-codec-decode-position-invalid-start-byte

Comment: This is not readable data, so you can't decode it as utf-8.

Comment: @tkausl so is there any way to make this readable?

Comment: @tkausl this may be readable data, but it's definitely not utf-8.

Comment: *`is there any way to make this readable?`* - What you show in the question is the in my opinion best way to make it readable.

Comment: You say *from a catalog* -- please add ***what*** catalog you are/were using.

Answer (score 4):

The [UTF-8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) has some built-in redundancy that serves at least two purposes:

### 1) locating code points reading back and forth

Start bytes (in binary dots carrying actual data) match one of these 4 patterns

```
0.......
110.....
1110....
11110...
```

whereas continuation bytes (0 to 3) have always this form

```
10......
```

### 2) checking for validity

If this encoding is not respected, it is safe to say that it is not UTF-8 data, e.g. because corruptions occurred during a transfer.

### Conclusion

Why is it possible to say that `b'\x80\'` cannot be UTF-8?
Already at the first two bytes the encoding is violated: because 80 must be a continuation byte. This is **exactly** what your error message says:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

And even if you skip this one, you get another problem some bytes later at `b'%\x83'`, so it's most likely that either you are trying to decode the wrong data or assume the wrong encoding.

Comment: If you donvoted, please explain what's wrong with this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Not my downvote, but merely demonstrating that UTF-8 is not the correct encoding for this data is a halfway answer at best. It seems obvious to me that the input is not text at all, so discussing the features of one particular text encoding seems completely tangential.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the hint. I'm maybe a bit too obsessed of UTF-8 here. My idea was to show that we can be sure about the correctness of the error message.

Answer (score 3):

You can try ignoring the non-readable blocks.

`blobs.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')`

It's not a great solution but the way you're generating the byte object has some issues. Maybe, `utf-8` is not the proper encoding for your data.

Comment: There are `\` in your byte which is a problem for string in python. Those may have to replaced with `\\`.

Comment: This is wrong on so many levels. Effectively extracting just the ASCII bytes from data which is predominantly not ASCII is hardly ever going to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The data in your example is clearly not text in any common encoding. Neither Python nor we can figure out a way to turn data which is obviously not text into strings.

If this is a well-defined binary file format, find a parser for this format (ideally a popular Python library, but for more obscure or proprietary formats you may not be able to find one) or write one yourself if you can figure out how the data is structured, either by clever experimentation and good guesswork, or by finding (if not authoritative then perhaps more or less speculative third-party) documentation.

If you simply want to turn the bytes into a string of code points with the same Unicode code points (so that for example the input byte `\xff` maps to the Unicode code point [U+00FF](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ff/index.htm)), the `'latin-1'` encoding does this, obscurely but conveniently. The result in this case will obviously not be useful human-readable text; in many ways, it would then be more natural and quite possibly less error-prone and more convenient to just keep the data as `bytes` instead.

Comment: Maybe a hexdump could also help. But I think the question *what* catalog was used will be the key.

Answer (score 0):

For this encoding error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

or other like that, you just have to open the database file with **.json** extension and change the encoding to UTF-8 (for exemple in VScode, you can change it in right-bottom nav-bar) and save the file...

Now run

```
 $ git status
```

you'll have something like this result

```
 On branch master
 Changes not staged for commit:
   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   store/dumps/store.json
   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore

 no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

or something like this one

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   store/dumps/store.json
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .gitignore
```

for the first case, you just have to do this one

```
$ git add store/dumps/
```

the second case don't need this previous part...

Now, for the two cases, you have to commit the changes with

```
$ git commit -m "launching to production"
```

the console will return you a message informed you for the adds and changes...

You have to build log for the app again with

```
$ git push heroku master
```

(for heroku users)

after the build, you just have to load the database again with

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata store/dumps/store.json
```

it will install the objects./.

excuses for my english level !!!

Comment: This seems quite misdirected. A JSON file should by definition contain UTF-8 already. I guess you assume the file contains a different encoding, and probably that the OP is a Windows user.