# can't read pickle from azure blob

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, utf-8, azure-blob-storage, pickle

I'm trying to save a sklearn model on azure blob storage.

I have no issue to save it and use it locally :

```
pickle.dump(random_forest, open("mymodel.pkl", 'wb'))
model = pickle.load(open("mymodel.pkl", "rb"))
```

==>This works like a charm.

But whenever i am trying to save it on azure blob storage, i cannot read it :

```
model= pickle.dumps(random_forest_model) 
blobService.create_blob_from_bytes(containerName, 'random_forest_model.pickle',model)
model= blobService.get_blob_to_bytes(containerName,'random_forest_model.pickle').content
model = pickle.load(open(model, "rb"))
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 import pickle
> ----> 2 model = pickle.load(open(model, "rb"))
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position
> 0: invalid start byte

I have read several other answers, without success. I have tried "error ignore", but i get the same error log.
[error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42339876/error-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xff-in-position-0-in)
[Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170614/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-0)

I am using azure-storage==0.36. For text files, it works very well.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
```

Any observation or suggestion would be highly appreciated!