# xmltodict 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte'

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I am trying to read an XML.dump file using 'xmltodict' library with python 3 to make a dictionary from this file.
The code I used is like:

```
import xmltodict

with open('file1.xml.dump') as fd:
    content = fd.read()
    doc = xmltodict.parse(content)
```

The error that I got is:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Does anyone know what this error is about of this error and how to fix this problem?

I also added `encoding='UTF-8'` in the `with open` statement, and I get the same error.

Comment: please give the utf encoding while opening the file\

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar `open` used `UTF-8` by default, that's what caused the error. The file isn't UTF-8

Comment: I wasn't talking about utf-8 encoding

Comment: What were you talking about? Why do you assume the file uses UTF16 or UTF32 instead of eg Latin1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62170614/python-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x80-in-position-0)

Comment: Sarah, btw, this has nothing to do with XML, since that code is never called. See [mcve], too. Further, I found this answer by just searching for the error message online.

Comment: @ Ulrich Eckhardt, thanks for trying to help me. But I saw this answer and it did not work for me.  I think there is something related to xml.dump file that I have, but I am not sure and I do not know what should I do to fix it.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, I've noticed that this file is not  UTF-8 but do you know what should I use instead?

Comment: @Sarah Ask whoever created the file.

Comment: We can't know what encoding was used for that file and why it wasn't UTF8, the de-facto standard, *especially* for XML files. Are you sure it's even XML? XML documents start with `<`. Either the file isn't XML at all or contains extra text before the XML part

Comment: What is `XML.dump` anyway? That's not a common file format or even name, much less an XML file format. How was this file generated? Can you open it with a text editor?

Comment: @ Sören You think with adding the correct encoding, this problem will fix?

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, I am sure that it was an XML file then someone did something to this file( I think like parse or whatever), then I have the file in this format: name.xml.dump. I tried to open it to see what is inside this file but apparently, I can not.  The computer just crashed. I think because it is too large.

Answer (score 1):

I just stepped into this error.

In my case it was caused by a float assigned to the #text node.

```
      'field': {
        '@attribute': 'm3',
        '#text': 10.076
      }
```

The assign it's valid but raises the encoding error.

The most easy fix it's to assign the value in an f string like this:

```
'field': {
        '@attribute': 'm3',
        '#text': f'{10.076}'
      }
```

So I would suggest you to review your dictionary and verify that all the root fields are indeed strings.